# How to find the desired zoom level to show a geographical location in Android mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

I want to show a city or province or a country in an Android mapview. Zoom level to show a city will be different than zoom level to show the entire country.

Let me know how can I find the desire zoom level for a location to show the entire location with its bounds.